# Indicating (non) transfer of ownership with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
class Node {
public:
    Node(Node* parent = 0) : mParent(parent) {}
    virtual ~Node() {
        for(auto p : mChildren) delete p;
    }

    // Takes ownership
    void addChild(Node* n);

    // Returns object with ownership
    Node* firstChild() const;

    // Does not take ownership
    void setParent(Node* n) { mParent = n; }

    // Returns parent, does not transfer ownership
    Node* parent() const { return mParent; }

private:
list<Node*> mChildren;
Node* mParent;
};
```

I'd now like to use smart pointers and/or rvalue references to indicate where ownership is and isn't transferred.

My first guess would be to change `mChildren` to contain `unique_ptr`s, adapting the function signatures as follows.

```
    // Takes ownership
    void addChild(unique_ptr<Node> n);

    // Returns object with ownership
    unique_ptr<Node>& firstChild() const;

    // Does not take ownership
    void setParent(Node* n) { mParent = n; }

    // Returns parent, does not transfer ownership
    Node* parent() const { return mParent; }
```

Now, this would be kind of problematic when I need to pass the result of `Node::firstChild()` to some function that observes it, but does not take ownership, as I'd need to explicitly call `.get()` on the `unique_ptr`, which as I understand it, is not recommended.

What is the correct and recommended way to indicate ownership using `unique_ptr` without having to resort to using `.get()` and passing around bare pointers?

Comment: Why not passing it to the function as a reference to const unique_ptr ? That way, the function can peek at it, and no copy is made.

Comment: @JBL because e.g. `parent()` returns a non-unique pointer, meaning I'd have to overload each function for raw and unique pointers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At first, I would use `std::vector` rather than `std::list` to contain the children. Unless you have a strong motivation for *not* using it, `std::vector` should be the default container. If you are worried about performance, don't be, because contiguous allocation done by `std::vector` is likely to cause higher cache hit rate, thus speeding up access enormously with respect to `std::list`, which implies a scattered allocation/access pattern.

Secondly, you are correct in having a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>>` for holding children, since it is reasonable to assume a node to hold ownership of its child nodes. All other pointers except the one accepted by `addChild()`, on the other hand, should be non-owning raw pointers.

This applies to the `mParent` pointer and to pointers returned by `Node`'s member functions. In fact the, `firstChild()` member function could even return a *reference*, throwing an exception if the node has no children. This way you will create no confusion whatsoever about who is owning the returned object.

Returning a `unique_ptr`, or a reference to a `unique_ptr`, is not the correct idiom: unique pointers represent ownership, and you do not want to give ownership to clients of `Node`.

This is how your class could look like:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>

class Node {
public:
    Node() : mParent(nullptr) { }

    void addChild(std::unique_ptr<Node>&& ptr) {
        mChildren.push_back(std::move(ptr));
        ptr->setParent(this);
    }

    Node& firstChild() const {
        if (mChildren.size() == 0) { throw std::logic_error("No children"); }
        else return *(mChildren[0].get());
    }

    Node& parent() const {
        if (mParent == nullptr) { throw std::logic_error("No parent"); }
        else return *mParent;
    }

private:

    void setParent(Node* n) { 
        mParent = n; 
    }

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> mChildren;
    Node* mParent;
};
```

You could of course decide to return non-owning, potentially null raw pointers instead of references if you want to avoid throwing exceptions. Or you could add a pair of `hasParent()` and `getNumOfChildren()` methods to retrieve information about a `Node`'s state. That would allow clients to perform the check if they do not want to handle exceptions.

Comment: I might have to make a lot of middle insertions/removals which is why I initially chose std::list over std::vector.

Comment: @SeySayux: `std::vector` may still be superior because of a higher cache hit rate (although complexity is worse, in practice memory access pattern dominates). Try doing some measurements before you commit to `std::list`.

Comment: Is it necessary / advantageous to take a `unique_ptr` by rvalue-ref instead of by value?

Comment: @DyP: It is a matter of style. It is not necessary in this case, because clients will have to do `std::move()` anyway, but in general it may be needed to express the fact that you want clients to provide an rvalue (and if they want to pass an lvalue, they have to `std::move()` it). So I am doing it even here, although for non-copyable classes like `std::unique_ptr` it is not strictly necessary, since clients can *only* provide rvalues.

Comment: @SeySayux will you be inserting and removing from the middle an order of magnitude more often than you will be iterating over the container?  I doubt it.  `c.erase( std::remove_if( c.begin(), c.end(), [&]()->bool{ code } ), c.end() );` gives you O(n) iterate-and-remove-elements, and similar tricks can be used to insert batches into the middle of your container.